# Como distorcer uma imagem usando o Canvas do HTML 5

Tags: html5, asp, canvas

Preciso aplicar esta imagem:
[image: cachorro]

Em formas diferentes, como copos, braceletes, camisetas, como estes exemplos
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei com componente do `AspJpeg`, mas vi com os desenvolvedores que fizeram esse componente que não é possível arredondar do modo que preciso, somente aplicação reta.

Agora estou estudando um modo de ser por `HTML5` com a tag `Canvas`, mas não estou conseguindo.

Obrigado pessoal!

Comment: Gustavo, você quer que as bordas da imagem fiquem arrendondadas, somente isso? http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/html5-css3-generators/border-radius-html5-css3-tools-generators.jpg . Veja se é algo parecido que deseja (retângulo cinza da imagem)

Comment: Não, o que preciso é que a imagem também fique no formato, entorte junto

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer isso requer um trabalho muito grande, pois requer uma modificação ponto a ponto.

Veja essa demonstração que pude encontrar [<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/LTXXp/2)

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22377416/how-to-warp-image